# universal way to launch navigation apps

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to be able to start turn by turn navigation using whatever the users of my app prefer as their navigation app.  The problem is that depending on what app the user has I need to send a different URI to start navigation.  I'm using Xamarin Android, but since the question is about what URI to use with the intent I believe any solution would be the same as for a native android app.

This URI format works to launch navigation in Google Maps and Tom Tom Go.  But if I try to use Waze it just shows my current location and completely ignores the location I sent it.

```
var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(String.Format($"google.navigation:q={lat},{lon}"));
var mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, geoUri);
StartActivity(mapIntent);
```

If I instead use this URI, Wave and Tom Tom Go both start navigation; but Google maps just shows the location instead of starting to navigate to it.

```
var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(String.Format($"geo:{lat},{lon}"));
```

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

Comment: @elmorabea my second URI example was supposed to be from that family (wasn't because of a copy/paste error).